# Is there a way to get a 2d slice of 3d matrix (nested lists)

Tags: python

I'm have some data that is being stored in a 3x3x3 nested list and I want to get 2d layers form that list.

for example I want to do something like a[:, :,2], a[0,:,:] or a[:,1,:] on the following list:

```
a=[
[
    [(0, 0, 0), (0, 0, 1), (0, 0, 2)],
    [(0, 1, 0), (0, 1, 1), (0, 1, 2)],
    [(0, 2, 0), (0, 2, 1), (0, 2, 2)],
],
[
    [(1, 0, 0), (1, 0, 1), (1, 0, 2)],
    [(1, 1, 0), (1, 1, 1), (1, 1, 2)],
    [(1, 2, 0), (1, 2, 1), (1, 2, 2)],
],
[
    [(2, 0, 0), (2, 0, 1), (2, 0, 2)],
    [(2, 1, 0), (2, 1, 1), (2, 1, 2)],
    [(2, 2, 0), (2, 2, 1), (2, 2, 2)],
],]
```

to get:

```
[
[(0, 1, 0), (0, 1, 1), (0, 1, 2)],
[(1, 1, 0), (1, 1, 1), (1, 1, 2)],
[(2, 1, 0), (2, 1, 1), (2, 1, 2)],]
```

I tried that but doing a[:][1][:] does nothing to the list so I just get a[1] which looks like this:

```
[
[(1, 0, 0), (1, 0, 1), (1, 0, 2)],
[(1, 1, 0), (1, 1, 1), (1, 1, 2)],
[(1, 2, 0), (1, 2, 1), (1, 2, 2)],]
```

I don't think I can use numpy because I'm using jython which doesn't support libraries implemented in c.

Can you help me find a way to do it nicely (or find a library like numpy that works on jython)?

Answer (score 2):

This will gather up the middle rows of each sub-matrix:

```
[x[1] for x in a]
```

Comment: sorry I wasn't clear, I want to be able to slice the cube in any direction and get any layer for example a[:, :,2] or a[0,:,:] and not only a[:,1,:].
I edited the question to clarify